# Can someone explain to me why i'm getting this error*** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax make: ***

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm new to Makefiles and i've come accross this error "*** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax make: ***" and i i'm not sure how to deal with it

```
/* here is my makefile */
CC=gcc          
CFLAGS= -g -Wall
LIBS=           
TARGET= test    

SRC_DIR = sourceFiles   
OBJ_DIR = home  
INC_DIR = headerFiles   
_DEPS = flags.h errorhandling.h helpmenu.h      
_OBJS = errorhandling.c calculator.c helpmenu.c

DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(INC_DIR)/%,$(_DEPS))
OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(OBJ_DIR)/%,$(_OBJS))

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

I get this error

```
Makefile:15: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
make: *** No rule to make target '/%.c', needed by 'home'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Please always cut and paste the exact error message you get (with proper formatting), rather than paraphrasing it.  In this situation, showing the exact error message would show us the line number in the makefile where make found the problem.  In fact, there is nothing in the makefile you've shown here that would give that warning so there must be something else going on that you've not shown us.  Seeing the exact error message would help.

Comment: sorry, i'll edit it now

Comment: The error message looks like you actually have `$(OBJ_DIR): /%.c`

Comment: You might be able to get a successful build simply by removing the offending rule altogether, since none of the other rules use the object files it seems to be trying to build. Moreover, with that rule appearing first in the makefile, its first target usurps the role of default target, which surely you intend to fall instead to `$(TARGET)`.

Comment: Also, if you are new to `make` then you would be well advised to start simply.  Put your sources and makefile in the same directory, and plan to build intermediate files and final results into that same directory.  Avoid pattern rules (and suffix rules) until you understand pretty well how to use regular rules to get the job done.  Similarly, avoid complex text manipulations such as with `$(patsubst)` until you understand how to do it without.  Maybe avoid GNU extensions (`$(patsubst)` among them) altogether, but certainly use them sparingly and with discretion.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yeah you're right. Although i can build it when they're in the same directory with any of the complex text manipulations. But the next step was, to try and build with the files in multiple directories

Comment: So avoid introducing so many changes at once, @Kus.  If the point is to learn how to build objects in different directories than their sources (which is a weirdly frequent and IMO overrated objective) then do it first with explicit rules and no variables.  This isn't directly related to your actual problem, but you have *a lot* of other issues with your makefile, too.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have spurious whitespace at the end of your `OBJ_DIR` variable assignment:

```
OBJ_DIR = home
```

You can never have any extra characters at the end of a variable assignment, including whitespace, because make includes those characters in the variable value.

So, `'$(OBJ_DIR)'` expands to `'home '` and `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.c` expands to `home /%.c`.